# How to using onlick() event when click button like in facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a sample code:

```
<fb:like onclick="example();displayThread('likepost')" href="http://stackoverflow.com" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:23px;"></fb:like>
```

And javascript

```
function example() {
    alert('test');
}
```

[image: like]
When I like page And click on button like is javascript can't work(alert('test')), how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put a `div` tag outside `fb:like` tag and add the event onClick within that `div` tag, that should work.

Comment: i want click on button like, is javascript will run

Comment: since like button is within div, so click on like button means click on that div.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function () {
    example();
});
//or
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', example);
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/